# How to link using jinja in django with the {% url 'index' %}? Constant errors

Tags: django, python-3.x, jinja2

After adding the jinja script I get a TypeError at line 0

The file about.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %}
<section id="showcase-inner" class="py-5 text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="display-4">About BT Real Estate</h1>
        <p class="lead">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt,
          pariatur!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Breadcrumb -->
<section id="bc" class="mt-3">
  <div class="container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="**{% url 'index' %}**"> <i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">About</li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Sam\Coding\Udemy\Python Django\btre_project\templates\base.html, error at line 0

'set' object is not reversible

```
{% load static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.css' %}" />
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" />
```

Comment: `{% load static %}` must be the very first line

Comment: Could you include the contents of `urls.py` where the path of `index` view is defined?

Answer (score 0):

BASE.HTML

```
{% load static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.css' %}" />
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" />

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

here we have to write block body in base.html file

ABOUT.HTML

```
    {% load static %} {% extends '(appname)/base.html' %}{% block body %}
<section id="showcase-inner" class="py-5 text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="display-4">About BT Real Estate</h1>
        <p class="lead">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt,
          pariatur!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Breadcrumb -->
<section id="bc" class="mt-3">
  <div class="container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="**{% url 'index' %}**"> <i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">About</li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>{%endblock%}
```

in about.html we have to specify block by block body tag.